# AWK: How to remove data where column count is not the same as header count and data has commas within double quotes

Tags: bash, awk

I need to remove lines of data where the column count is not the same as the header column count. The following works except in the case where a field contains data, which has commas in it within double quotes. Any ideas how to fix please?

```
cleanColumns=$(awk -F, 'NR==1{ count=NF; } NF==count' testData.txt);
echo  "$cleanColumns" > noErrors.tx
```

Before

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,dataType,success,bytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,Hostname,IdleTime,Connect
1459774220811,2018,Fizz_Homepage_2,403," transaction : 1,failing samples : 0",,false,12928,2,2,0,HOST1,5008,0
1459774225103,3485,Fizz_Launch_1,200," transaction : 1,failing samples : 0",,true,1138878,2,2,0,HOST1,5022,0
1459774227844,1653,Fizz_Launch_1,200," transaction : 1,failing samples : 0",,true,18792,2,2,0,HOST1,5012,0
1459774227844,1653,Fizz_Launch_1,200," transaction : 1,failing samples : 0",,true,18792,2,2,0,HOST1,
1459774227844,1653,Fizz_Launch_1,200," transaction : 1,failing samples : 0",,true,
```

After

```
1459774220811,2018,Fizz_Homepage_2,403," transaction : 1,failing samples : 0",,false,12928,2,2,0,HOST1,5008,0
1459774225103,3485,Fizz_Launch_1,200," transaction : 1,failing samples : 0",,true,1138878,2,2,0,HOST1,5022,0
1459774227844,1653,Fizz_Launch_1,200," transaction : 1,failing samples : 0",,true,18792,2,2,0,HOST1,5012,0
```

Comment: Use tool designed for parsing CSVs. For example, Python or Perl both have CSV modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU awk for FPAT:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]+"' 'NR==1{nf=NF} NF==nf' file
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,dataType,success,bytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,Hostname,IdleTime,Connect
1459774220811,2018,Fizz_Homepage_2,403," transaction : 1,failing samples : 0",,false,12928,2,2,0,HOST1,5008,0
1459774225103,3485,Fizz_Launch_1,200," transaction : 1,failing samples : 0",,true,1138878,2,2,0,HOST1,5022,0
1459774227844,1653,Fizz_Launch_1,200," transaction : 1,failing samples : 0",,true,18792,2,2,0,HOST1,5012,0
```

With other awks you need a `while(match())` loop with the same regex, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=RS; OFS="," }
{
    head = ""
    tail = $0
    while( (tail!="") && match(tail,/[^,]*|"[^"]+"/) ) {
        head = head (head==""?"":FS) substr(tail,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        tail = substr(tail,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)
    }
    $0 = head tail
}
NR==1 { nf=NF }
NF==nf { $1=$1; print }
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,dataType,success,bytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,Hostname,IdleTime,Connect
1459774220811,2018,Fizz_Homepage_2,403," transaction : 1,failing samples : 0",,false,12928,2,2,0,HOST1,5008,0
1459774225103,3485,Fizz_Launch_1,200," transaction : 1,failing samples : 0",,true,1138878,2,2,0,HOST1,5022,0
1459774227844,1653,Fizz_Launch_1,200," transaction : 1,failing samples : 0",,true,18792,2,2,0,HOST1,5012,0
```

The above does more than you need as it creates a record where each field is separated by newlines first and then changes the newlines back to commas before printing - that's so rather than just getting a count of the fields you can write loops on or otherwise access the fields etc. just as if you had used `FPAT`. Here's a general approach to the problem of identifying fields in CSV files when you don't have GNU awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    csv2flds()
    for (i=0;i<=NF;i++) {
        print "NR="NR, "NF="NF, "$"i"="$i
    }
    print "-----"
}

function csv2flds(      head, tail, ofs) {
    ofs=OFS; OFS=","; FS=RS
    head = ""
    tail = $0
    while( (tail!="") && match(tail,/[^,]*|"[^"]+"/) ) {
        head = head (head==""?"":FS) substr(tail,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        tail = substr(tail,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)
    }
    $0 = head tail      # calculates NF and splits into fields using FS="\n"
    $1 = $1             # converts "xFSy" into "xOFSy" so "x\ny" becomes "x,y"
    FS=OFS; OFS=ofs
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | head -32
NR=1 NF=14 $0=timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,dataType,success,bytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,Hostname,IdleTime,Connect
NR=1 NF=14 $1=timeStamp
NR=1 NF=14 $2=elapsed
NR=1 NF=14 $3=label
NR=1 NF=14 $4=responseCode
NR=1 NF=14 $5=responseMessage
NR=1 NF=14 $6=dataType
NR=1 NF=14 $7=success
NR=1 NF=14 $8=bytes
NR=1 NF=14 $9=grpThreads
NR=1 NF=14 $10=allThreads
NR=1 NF=14 $11=Latency
NR=1 NF=14 $12=Hostname
NR=1 NF=14 $13=IdleTime
NR=1 NF=14 $14=Connect
-----
NR=2 NF=14 $0=1459774220811,2018,Fizz_Homepage_2,403," transaction : 1,failing samples : 0",,false,12928,2,2,0,HOST1,5008,0
NR=2 NF=14 $1=1459774220811
NR=2 NF=14 $2=2018
NR=2 NF=14 $3=Fizz_Homepage_2
NR=2 NF=14 $4=403
NR=2 NF=14 $5=" transaction : 1,failing samples : 0"
NR=2 NF=14 $6=
NR=2 NF=14 $7=false
NR=2 NF=14 $8=12928
NR=2 NF=14 $9=2
NR=2 NF=14 $10=2
NR=2 NF=14 $11=0
NR=2 NF=14 $12=HOST1
NR=2 NF=14 $13=5008
NR=2 NF=14 $14=0
-----
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `gawk` you can set up FPAT variable to define fields (instead of field separator).

for example

```
 gawk -v FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" 'NR==1{count=NF} NF==count' file
```

Answer (score 1):

An example of using a CSV parser: a perl-like ruby one-liner

```
ruby -rcsv -ne '
    row = CSV.parse_line($_)
    n = row.length if $. == 1
    puts $_ if row.length == n
' filename
```